# instances/setMachineResources equivalent in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

From what I can tell the REST API has support for setting machine resources for existing instances (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances/setMachineResources), but I cannot find any equivalent commands for gcloud. Can resources (GPUs in particular) currently be added/removed using gcloud, and if so how?

Comment: Currently there is no equivalent `gcloud` flag for this API. If you're interested in updating this resource via `gcloud` command, I encourage you to open a feature request on [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) and we'll be glad to look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in gcloud, setting accelerator is only possible in 'gcloud instances create' and not 'gcloud instances update'.